# SFTP Default Folder & Limiting Access With chroot

Tags: openssh, sftp, chroot

I want to default a given user to a specific folder when they SFTP to my Ubuntu 18.04 machine. I also wanted to lock down SFTP a bit. [This Digital Ocean post gave me what I needed, and helped me get a start, but it's not working as I hoped it would](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-enable-sftp-without-shell-access-on-ubuntu-18-04).

I created a folder called /var/sftp/my_username. Then I updated sshd_config to include these settings:

```
Match User my_username
ForceCommand internal-sftp
PasswordAuthentication yes
ChrootDirectory /var/sftp/
PermitTunnel no
AllowAgentForwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
X11Forwarding no
```

My hope was that my_username would land in /var/sftp/my_username and be trapped there. Instead, the user lands in /var/sftp and must open'my_username' in order to move to a directory that they can upload to. This is a problem because /var/sftp will eventually list other sftp subfolders for other users (IE /var/sftp/your_username).

What can I do to default this user to /var/sftp/my_username? I have already tried changing the user's home directory this this location, without luck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to change the entry 'ChrootDirectory /var/sftp/' in sshd_config to something like 'ChrootDirectory /var/sftp/my_username'

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Olav. I did try that in my original troubleshooting. It does not work. I'm not able to set up ChrootDirectory to any directory that Root does not own.

I solved this problem by just creating an additional folder layer:

ChrootDirectory /var/sftp/my_username/my_username

The /var/sftp folder has several usernames for different users. Each user is Chroot'd to their top level my_username folder. They cannot write to /var/sftp/my_username but they own /var/sftp/my_username/my_username and can just open that subfolder and do as they please.

This gives them write ability and hides other folders from other users.